# Can I use a fondue bourguignonne set to make cheese fondue?

Tags: equipment, fondue

I have a fondue bourguignonne set ([this model](http://www.amazon.it/fonduta-bourguignonne-smalto-bianco-collection/dp/B00CKLA7JG)). Can I use it to make cheese fondue? The manual explicitly says that it is not suitable for chocolate fondue, but it says nothing about cheese fondue.

(BTW, I am also curious to know why it is not suitable for making chocolate or possibly cheese fondue. Is the réchaud too powerful?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a fondue bourguignonne (oil) or Chinoise (broth), *raw* ingredients are cooked in the pot, which means you need to get the liquid at least close to a boil, i.e. in the 90-100 C range. The burner under your model should easily supply enough heat.

For chocolate fondue, this would mean the chocolate would burn almost instantly. If you serve a chocolate fondue with a heat source at all, you'd use probably a tea light (small candle) at a distance.

Cheese fondue can take more heat than chocolate, but less than broth or oil. The idea is to just keep the warm cheese liquid. *If* you can reduce the power of your burner a bit, e.g. by closing the outer holes, you should be ok. Just pre-melt the cheese mix gently on the stove, not over the flame of the rechaud and never forget the "stirring rule": each participant is to use his bread on the fork to stir once or so over the bottom, to ensure the cheese doesn't stick. If you use a heavy ceramic pot instead of a metal one, it would be even better, but your set should work, too.